# How difference between use name-based virtual hosts or host headers?

Tags: web-server, web-hosting

I start my own server to host web sites, and on this beggin i came across this question:

How difference between use name-based virtual hosts or host headers?

Comment: SF is not here to teach you basics. You need to go learn on your own, then start implementing what you've learned. After you've done that, come back with reasonably-scoped, we'll-researched questions about things you've run into during your work.

Comment: @Tero Killanen, oh SU is better, tks... I had asked to my friend how channel is better for this line question, i think he forgot how hand is left and right, i say fo him...

Answer (score 1):

Both perform the same function.

virtual hosts is the name of the function in Apache and Ngninx (among other) web servers,  while host headers is the name of the same function in Microsoft Internet Information Server.

Comment: Tks for atention man ...i just need read more somethings to evaluate right

Answer (score 0):

**Client Host Header**

Host headers are the HTTP/1.1+ header sent by the client that provides the `Host:` name you are connecting to.  *e.g:*

```
Host: serverfault.com
```

**Server using the Host Header**

Name-Based Virtual Hosts are a way to host multiple websites on one server using the same IP address and differentating the sites using the previously mentioned `Host:` header.